# Listing file for assembly code

Tags: assembly, 8051

I am trying to generate a .LST (listing) file from some assembly code (.asm) that I have. I tried to use Keil but could not generate it. Can anyone please highlight the steps to generate .lst file from the .asm version.

Comment: What assembler do you use?

Answer (score 2):

All I do to generate a .lst file is to assemble the .asm file.

1. Create a project
2. Add the ASM file
3. Build the project

Now you have your .lst file in the Listings folder of your project.

For me this is done with Keil uVision V5.14.2.1 and just doing a default project. I picked 'Nordic Semiconductors nRF24LE1' circuit since that is the one I'm using.

Answer (score 2):

My way:

1. Open Project ,
2. Create a file (*).asm AND  write  code
3. Go to `Property` of `Project`: ( note `platform` for correct in first line - for me: `WIN32` )
4. Go to `Microsoft Macro Assembler` - `Listing file` - set `Yes(/Sg)` Enable Assembly Generated Code Listing
   and set `$(ProjectName).lst` in `Assembled Code Listing File`
5. Go to `property` of file (*).asm  do the same thing as above...
   Thanks for watch

Answer (score -3):

1. Save your code in the Notepad.
2. Save your code on your C:\ drive.
3. Run the DOS BOX.
4. Write this (mount c c:\here write your folder name and then press Enter key)
5. Create `obj` and `lst` like this (nasm your program name.asm -o 1.com -l 1.lst press Enter kay)
6. Write afd 1.com.

Comment: This question is about 8051, not 8086.  NASM isn't an 8051 assembler, and DOSBox doesn't emulate an 8051.  Also, for 8086, you don't need to run NASM inside DOSBox to get a listing; NASM is portable and `-fbin` is the default on any build of NASM, including native Linux or Windows.  You only need DOSBox (or some other 16-bit environment) if you want to actually *run* obsolete 16-bit .com executables, not to create them.

Answer (score -4):

1. Save your File with (.asm)
2. Create your .Obj file with (MASM File_name.ASM)
3. Create your .exe file with (Link File_name)
4. Create your .com file with (exe2bin  File_name  File_name.com)
5. Create your  .LST file with (File_name.LST)

Comment: Not even the correct answer when using MASM, let alone the Keil assembler mentioned in the question.